# finding contrapositive of logical statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am familiar with the contraposition definition of if P then Q and if Q then P, as well as real world examples such as "if all cats are animals" then "if something is a cat, it is an animal" . However I am confused when applying it t to something more abstract such as:

*“If x^2 is even, then so is x”, where x is an integer*

where do I begin to find the contraposition of the statement?

Comment: The contrapositive of $P \rightarrow Q$ is $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$. In your first example, the contrapositive would be: If "something is a cat and it is not an animal" then it implies that "not all cats are animals".

Answer (score 2):

The contrapositive of "if $P$ then $Q$" is "if not $Q$ then not $P$". 
 What you have is "if $x^2$ is even, then $x$ is even", so with $P$ as "$x^2$ is even" and $Q$ as "$x$ is even", the contrapositive is "if $x$ is odd, $x^2$ is odd".

Comment: i understand now, thank you

Comment: Your last comment contradicts the sentence "I am familiar with the contraposition definition of if P then Q". You seems to confuse contraposition and converse.

Comment: Given $P$ implies $Q$, the contrapositive is "not $Q$ implies not $P$". The converse is "$Q$ implies $P$". You've written the converse in your comment because you haven't negated anything.